# Find $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Find the limit of
>
> $$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n dx$$

Let $$u= 1 +\frac{x}{n} \implies du =\frac{1}{n} dx \implies n \cdot du = dx$$
at $x=0$ $u=1$ and at $x=1$   $u=1+\frac{1}{n}$  so now limit will change from $1$ to $1+\frac{1}{n}$

Back to the integral

$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( n \cdot \int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n}} u^n du \right)= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( n \cdot \left[ \frac{nu^{n+1}}{n+1} \right]_1^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \right) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n^2}{n+1}  \left[  u^{n+1} \right]_1^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \right) $$

$$\implies\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n^2}{n+1}  \left[  \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}-1 \right] \right)=\infty$$

Is my finding correct? Is the procedure of taking the limit before completing the integration correct?

Much appreciated

Comment: Take the limit inside and obtain $e-1$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Requires some rigor.

Comment: @MariosGretsas  I am not familiar with this. But, I think I am supposed to relate it to , unfortunately, I have no examples references in my book.

Comment: Perhaps you can see your mistake easily. The integral for $u^{n} $ is $u^{n+1}/(n+1)$ and you have added an extra factor $n$ due to which you are getting wrong answer. And your approach is much better passing limit inside integral sign.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to change the limits of the integral. The integral limits should be $1$ and $1+\frac{1}{n}$.

In particular, $$n\int_{1}^{1+1/n} u^n du = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Honestly though, the only answer that answers the OP's questions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Indeed, these sorts of questions tend to get five answers that are some flashy technique that has nothing to do with the asker's attempt, and maybe a comment pointing out the error. (+1) for a good and on-point answer.

Comment: Thanks @SimplyBeautifulArt and user296602.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converges uniformly against $e^x$ on the interval $[0,1]$, hence you are allowed to swap the limit with the integral.

Comment: Thx for the input How do you find out that $\left( 1+ \frac{x}{n} \right)$ converges uniformly against $e^x$?

Comment: @gegu It may be more intuitive to use the monotone convergence theorem, seeing as $(1+\frac xn)^n$ converging monotonically is a well known fact.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$\left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n
\to e^x
$,

$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n dx
= \int_{0}^{1} e^x dx
=e-1
$.

Comment: @gegu What's your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: By definition: $e^x = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+ \frac{x}{n} )^n$. Thx. Struggling in finding definitions.